# Android data binding error en compilar error: package Models does not exist

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Amigos estoy trabajando en una app en la cual se ha implementado el data binding para la optimización de codigo a la hora de hacer la conexion con las views, resulta que al momento de compilar genera 4 errores los cuales son:

`error: cannot find symbol class Models`

`error: package Models does not exist`

`error: package Models does not exist`

`error: package Models does not exist`

En ese mismo orden los genera, se esta usando una clase modelo llama User, que se encuentra de del paquete `Models`, la cuestion es la siguiente, **SI** la clase se encuentra dentro del paquete, el compilador me genera esos errores, **PERO** si esta fuera de los paquetes, es decir en la raiz, el compilador no genera error.

Ahora se tiene que trabajar si o si bajo este esquema de carpetas por cuestiones de ordenamiento y buenas practicas.

Estos son las clases y views

**ChatActivity.java**

```
package edu.cecar.laws.Activities;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;
import edu.cecar.laws.Models.User;
import edu.cecar.laws.R;
import edu.cecar.laws.databinding.ActivityChatBinding;

public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final ActivityChatBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_chat);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        User user = new User("Jhonny Sierra","24","j@j.com");
        binding.setChatView(user);

        binding.btnEnviarMensaje.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String men = binding.txtMensaje.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, men, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**User.java**

```
package edu.cecar.laws.Models;

public class User {

    private String nombre;
    private String edad;
    private String email;

    public User(String nombre, String edad, String email) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    public void setEdad(String edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "nombre='" + nombre + '\'' +
                ", edad='" + edad + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**activity_chat.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="chatView"
            type="edu.cecar.laws.Models.User" />
    </data>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Activities.ChatActivity"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="16sp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/fotoPerfil"
                android:layout_width="48sp"
                android:layout_height="48sp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nombreUser"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{chatView.nombre}"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvMensaje"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            >
        </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtMensaje"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:hint="Mensaje"
                android:background="@drawable/reg_edittext_style"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnEnviarMensaje"
                android:layout_width="48sp"
                android:layout_height="48sp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"
                android:background="@drawable/reg_btn_style"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

Y esta es la estructura de carpeta que se esta manejando.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver existen dos clases que hacen referencia a los mismo `Usuario` y `User`, al implementar `Usuario` no genera ningún error en cambio con la otra si, alguien podría ayudar en este dilema

Comment: > Podría probar el cambio en el nombramiento del paquete de Models todas minisculas y correr nuevamente el proyecto. Espero sea de gran ayuda mi respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: Si ese era el problema, la mayúscula en el nombre de la carpeta

Answer (score 0):

La estructura que tienes definida para el acceso a las clases es correcta, si experimentas un problema y la estructura es correcta, generalmente el problema se debe  a desincronización del proyecto, aquí solo debes limpiar y reconstruir el proyecto:

`Clean` -> `Rebuild`

Pero en este caso tienes un bloque en tu layout ( `<data>` ) el cual no es permitido y puede causar este tipo de errores ya que estas definiendo el acceso a una clase, debes eliminarlo:

```
    ...
    ...
    <data>
        <variable
            name="chatView"
            type="edu.cecar.laws.Models.User" />
    </data>
    ...
    ...
```